# How to View SSRS Report (.rdl) in Windows Forms from Same Solution

Tags: vb.net

**I have two different project First is Windows Application and second is Report Project**
**So How can I view report in my First Project**

Here's attached screenshot of Both Projects

[image: 1]

Answer (score 1):

RDL reports get installed in an instance of SQL Server Reporting Services (SSRS) you then load the report into a `ReportViewer` control from that server. That's a subject too big to include in a single answer here and you should research it independently and then ask specific questions later if you have them.

If you want the reports to be part of your application itself then you need to create client reports - RDLC files - rather than server reports. There is a VS extension you can install for creating client reports, if that's what you want.